# assigning parent_id from an existing attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a database that is imported from a CSV file and I would like to assign hierarchy based on the assembly level below. not sure which approach to take. I can write if statements but it will be very long. sorry I am new to this, and I don't know where to begin. any help is much appreciated.

```
assembly_level         assembly_tree           description      uniq_id
0                      zero level               "zero level"    d9s64
1                       level one assembly      "level one"     c9633
2                        level two assembly     "level two"     11197
3                         level three assembly  "level three"   e271f
4                          level four assembly  "level four"    552da
4                          level four assembly  "level four"    4568a
3                         level three assembly  "level three"   b72bd
```

how can I assign assembly_level to Parent_id during import?

@item = Item.new(:assembly_level=> params[:parent_id])

Comment: question is not clear. Please give more explanation with sample code it possible

Comment: @bunty, 
please see the question again thank you in advance!

Comment: @michaelfouad we need more context, i.e. more code! You should create a minimal, self-contained example that has as little irrelevant information as possible and clearly shows your problem. Ideally, the code should be copy + pasteable. http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are importing the content from the CSV file reading line by line and the little information you provide, I consider that (correct me if I am wrong) the hierarchy is implied in the order of the file.

I would try this:

- Whenever you store a record, you store the id of the record in a temporary variable.
- Then, I would check if the next record is a children. If so, I would assign the parent_id which I have just stored.

A sample of unverified code, so you can see what I am thinking:

```
previous_record['id'] = 0
previous_record['level'] = 999 # Temp variable with previous record

csv_file.read do |line| # Reading method of your choice
  line_array = line.split(";")
  item = Item.new({'assembly_level' => line_array[0], 'assembly_tree' => line_array[1], 'description' => line_array[2], 'uniq_id' => line_array[3]) # Creating regular item

  # If the current item is children the assembly level is greater than the previous one
  if item.assembly_level > previous_record['level']
    item.parent_id = previous_record['id']
    item.save
  else # Only store previous value when is not a children 
    # Storing values to use for the next record
    previous_record['id'] = line_array[3]
    previous_record['level'] = line_array[0]
  end
end
```